# How to increase the virtual coins when a banner ad is pressed

Tags: android, button, textview, android-edittext, banner-ads

> I have an app in which i have included virtual coins for the users to purchase things like new themes,skins etc etc....And the way to earn these virtual coins is to click on the banner ads(admob ads).Every time the user clicks on the ads the virtual coins should increase by 10.The problem is, i am not able to detect the click on the ads...How do i detect a click on the banner ad?
>   Note:I have integrated the admob ads through the XML file......So please dont give an answer which does it for the programatically defined admob ads.

Thanks :)

Comment: Doing this might ban you from the Admob program.

Comment: Really? Because i have seen big gaming platforms like "com2us" do this....

Comment: https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3342054 It's not clearly stateed though, but i think it covers this scenario

Answer (score 0):

You can use onInterceptTouchEvent. Please read more about this method. [onInterceptTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html)

// We intercept clicks

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean result = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    switch (event.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Click!
        break;
    }

    return result;
}
```